# How to enable / disable function apps in a resource group in azure

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-runbook

I an writing a **powershell** script which will run in **runbook**.
This script will first **disable the function apps** in the resource group, then another similar script will **enable the functions apps** in the resource group.

I already tried below script but it does not enable function apps

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try {
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint  } catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

$RGName = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'DRPrimaryResourceGroupName'
$FAppResources = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites" -ResourceGroupName $RGName -ExpandProperties  
$LAppResources = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.Logic/workflows" -ResourceGroupName $RGName -ExpandProperties 

ForEach ($FAResource in $FAppResources) {
        Write-Output ("*****************************************************************************************")
        Write-Output ("Starting FunctionApp "+ $FAResource.ResourceName+ " in Resource Group " +$RGName)
        Write-Output ("*****************************************************************************************")
        Start-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $RGName -Name $FAResource.ResourceName
        Write-Output ($FAResource.ResourceName + " and its status is " +  $FAResource.Properties.State)
}
ForEach ($LAResource in $LAppResources) {  
        Write-Output ("*****************************************************************************************")
        Write-Output ("Enabling Logic App "+ $LAResource.ResourceName +" in Resource Group"+ $RGName)  
        Write-Output ("***************************************************************************************")
        Set-AzureRmLogicApp -ResourceGroupName $RGName -Name $LAResource.ResourceName -State Enabled -Force
        Write-Output ($LAResource.ResourceName + " and its status is " +  $LAResource.Properties.State)
}
```

Comment: Is there a error message ?

Comment: Any update this issue? If it is helpful, please accept it as the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have seen the output of your runbook, it appeared like the screenshot below. So you think your script does not enable function app.

[image]

Actually, your script enables the function app, but the line
 `Write-Output ($FAResource.ResourceName + " and its status is " +  $FAResource.Properties.State)` just could write out the old state.

To fix the issue, you could try to add the line `$newstate = (Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $RGName -Name $FAResource.ResourceName).State`, it gets the new state after starting the function app,  write out the `$newstate`, then it will work fine.

*Complete script:*

```
ForEach ($FAResource in $FAppResources) {
        Write-Output ("*****************************************************************************************")
        Write-Output ("Starting FunctionApp "+ $FAResource.ResourceName+ " in Resource Group " +$RGName)
        Write-Output ("*****************************************************************************************")
        Start-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $RGName -Name $FAResource.ResourceName
        $newstate = (Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $RGName -Name $FAResource.ResourceName).State
        Write-Output ($FAResource.ResourceName + " and its status is " +  $newstate)
}
```

[image]